# Do any Marxists write about Ulysses' "nightmare of history"

Tags: marxism, literary-theory

> History is a nightmare from which I am trying to awake

Usually, it seems, associated with the artistic career of Joyce. But yes, it does sound like rich pickings for an aestheticising Marxist.

Do any Marxist critics do substantial work with that phrase?

Comment: Loosely speaking, Walter Benjamin does, or at least he suggests it. Best to start with the print by Paul Klee https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angelus_Novus

Comment: @Gordon vaguely aware of that, but hoping for an "answer" nonetheless

Comment: Yes I understand. Walter Benjamin did not write directly about the quote you gave, at least as far as I know.

Comment: i'm not sure, either. "nightmare of history" "benjamin" has 77,000 hits... @Gordon

Comment: Benjamin definitely wrote about the general idea of your quote. The wikipedia I link to above is a very famous example regarding what the Angelus Novus meant to the Left, and Benjamin's Theses on the Philosophy of is cited in this wikipedia article.

Comment: @Gordon sure. are you familiar with the source of these phrases? i'm not sure the question really makes sense now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63241/discussion-between-idiot-an-and-gordon).

Comment: It's a quote from Ulysee's by the main protagonist, Stephen Dedalus; it might be a reference to Marx, or it might be a reference to Irish history; after all Joyce is famous for leaving Ireland for Europe.

Comment: Adorno and Horkheimer are Marxists who wrote a chapter called "Odysseus or Myth and Enlightenment" in their opus "Dialectic of Enlightenment". I don't know if they are talking about the same thing that James mentions.

Answer (score 3):

1. Dedalus' 'History is a nightmare from which I am trying to awake' has an echo in Marx's 18th Brumaire of Louis Bonaparte :

> Men make their own history, but they do not make it just as they please; they
>   do not make it under circumstances chosen by themselves, but under circumstances directly encountered, given and transmitted from the past. The tradition of all the dead generations weighs like a nightmare on the brain of the living.

2. But since Joyce was not a Marxist, this is only a side comment. Eisenstein is a candidate as a Marxist who used Joyce. Take this quotation from a 1932 talk :

> Radek's critique of Joyce was based essentially on one point. He said that we don't need things in such microscopic detail. We don't see that way, such phenomena don't exist. But that criticism is as if a person at some first-aid station saw an enlargement of something seen under the microscope on the wall
>   and said: "Why is this necessary? After all, microbes aren't that big. After all, you don't see all that in real life." Do you understand the
>   mistake here? The thing is that you have to study those charts in
>   order to be able to know those invisible bacteria, those invisible
>   elements, in order to possess them. And that's the significance of
>   studying Joyce and it's on that level that he analyzes things so
>   microscopically. (James Joyce Quarterly, Vol. 24, No. 2 (Winter, 1987), p.137.)

This can be applied to history and can remove its nightmarish qualities. Macro-history is as bad as Marx said it was but it ceases to be dark and oppressive when macro-history is replaced by micro-history : the life of one person in the course of just a day described in 700 pages. Of course 'Ulysses' is not real history but its microscopic style and level of treatment can be applied to history, which then looks very different from the Marxist grand narrative. It does not reject that narrative but alters our perspective on it.

Answer (score 0):

Joyce's phrase echos Marx, as Benjamin. Further:

[image]

*Scare Quotes from Shakespeare*, p59

Comment: there are other things you could read, on joyce and benjamin.e.g. Joyce, Benjamin and Magical Urbanism. obviously i haven't, though

Answer (score 0):

Joyce's *bon mot* would not have been appreciated by any *bona fide* marxist. History and nightmares may be both horrible but this similarity is much weaker than the difference between real and unreal. The idea about 'waking from history' would be not only meaningless but also pernicious: it hints at some kind of unreality while marxism used to explain itself as 'historical *materialism*'. Having an end is another similarity but waking is something that happens more or less independently of you, while putting an end to history is the goal of a premeditated action - the Revolution. So, as the differences largerly outweight the similarities,  the   conjectured use would relie on a rather superficial analogy. The possibility of 'substantial work' appears to be excluded in advance.